# Convert a matrix so it can be multiplied on the right side, instead of the left

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Sometimes I come across examples of geometric transformations that multiply the transformation  matrix on the left side of the vector and sometimes on the right.

How do you modify a matrix so that when multiplied on the opposite side it will yield the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're thinking about $(Ax)^T=x^TA^T$, where $^T$ denotes transpose.

Comment: It is worth noting that any $f$ such that $xf(A)=Ax$ can't exist because the result dimensions will never agree. It does work with transpose as mentioned above.